# What are the reasons or advantages to use &my_array[0] instead of my_array in assignments?

Tags: c

I'm seeing this kind of assignment:

```
info->table = &_ttable_full[0];
```

Why not directly use this:

```
info->table = _ttable_full;
```

Is there any advantage? Or is it just the author's style?

Comment: There is no difference. Only style. Some people prefer more explicit way.

Comment: The advantage of the second option is that it takes less of your time when you type it. It also stores less information on your hard drive when you save this file, and will theoretically allow you for 4 more characters when you just about to run out of storage.

Comment: @0___________ I think I like that style because it's clear to the reader you're providing an address to something.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb in this particular case in the flash memory of my device. If I really depend on that 4 characters, I should delete my code and start over coding.

Comment: @FranciscoHerrera flaash on your device is taken by the generated code, not the source files.

Comment: @0___________ you're right. But still can save 4 characters on my laptop XD

Comment: To save more I think you need to change the naming convention Examples: `i->t=tf;`

Comment: @0___________ Why tf when you can use just f

Comment: I use it. It's just style. I don't like implicit array decay, so I make it explicit. Different folks have different stylistic quirks.

Comment: I must admit though that it's not a great way to make array decay explicit as it'll work with pointers too. I were super serious about it, I'd make a decay macro that'd throw a compiler error when given a pointer rather than an array. But using such a macro on SO might then confuse people even more than `&a[0]` does :D.

Comment: To be very clear: bbbbbbbbb's comment about saving four characters was a *joke*.  No one seriously worries about shaving a few characters here and there in C source code.

Comment: haha since his first comment, I noticed his hint of humor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the use you show, there is no difference in C semantics.

In some circumstances, I would use `A` to indicate the resulting pointer may be used to access the entire array, whereas `&A[0]` suggests the pointer is intended for use only to access that specific element. Similarly, `A+j` suggests the resulting address is the starting point for some algorithm, whereas `&A[j]` suggests that particular element is of interest. These are just to help the reader. Like using different typefaces in documents, they do not change the literal meaning of the text but help guide the reader in interpreting it.

Note there are some circumstances where `A` and `&A[0]` differ. `sizeof A` gives the size (number of bytes) of the array, whereas `sizeof &A[0]` gives the size of a pointer to an element of the array. `&A` gives a pointer to the array (which has a different type than a pointer to an element), whereas `&&A[0]` is not a normal part of the C grammar. (Some compilers may use `&&` in an extension.)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a stylistic convention to make it clear you're providing an address to an array.